# Build Project from Separate Solution

Tags: msbuild, exec, building

I have a .dll that my project uses which is generated by a project in a separate solution.

I have a conditional MSBuild `Target` which will build this project and copy the .dll if the .dll does not exist.

I am building with this command inside my `Target`:

```
<Exec Command="MSBuild Bar.vcxproj /p:Configuration=$(Configuration)" WorkingDirectory="..\..\Foo\Bar" />
```

Is there an MSBuild command that I could use to accomplish this other than `Exec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) for this, something like:

`<MSBuild Projects="..\..\Foo\Bar\Bar.vcxproj" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)"/>`